# connecting to remote sql express server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, permissions, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a program running with an EF model in c#. when running the app from my local computer everything runs great but when installing it on a different computer in my network it immediately stop responding. i noticed that after adding the specific user to the logins in SSMS everything works if i give him a sysadmin permission (public is not enough).
is it a security risk to give this permission? is there a way that upon first run of the program or during the setup the user will be automatically added to the logins of the sql server?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding every single user in Sql Server just create an Login that is mapped to a domain group (YOURDOMAIN\Users or a custom group if you want to limit access to a specific group of users) and has your database as the default database (instead of *master*).

Usually it should not be necessary to grant to `sysadmin` role if you create the aforementioned Login and grant `public` access to your database (User Mapping).

Comment: unfortunately the public privilege only generates an exception when trying to run the program, but when giving the sysadmin privilege it works.

Comment: Do your users need to create tables, views, etc.? In any case you should limit this to a defined group to avoid creating Logins for every single user.